# Can I in firestore get the list of ids of the documents in a collection without generating read operations?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have an ionic project and use firestore services

> Ionic:
>
> Ionic CLI                     : 6.19.0 (C:\Users\Windows
> 10\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli)    Ionic Framework
> : @ionic/angular 6.0.14    @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.3.1
> @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.3.1    @angular/cli
> : 13.3.1    @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0
>
> Capacitor:
>
> Capacitor CLI      : 3.4.3    @capacitor/android : 3.4.3
> @capacitor/core    : 2.4.5    @capacitor/ios     : not installed
>
> Utility:
>
> cordova-res : 0.15.4    native-run  : 1.5.0
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v16.14.2 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)    npm    :
> 8.5.0    OS     : Windows 10

Is there a way to get the list of ids of the documents that belong to a collection without generating a read operation?

example

```
constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
  ) { 
    afs.collection<Pais>('products').ref.onSnapshot( 
         products => products.forEach(product => console.log(product.id))
       );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to get any document information out of Firestore without incurring the cost of a read.  The cost of a read covers the use of the index that holds the document IDs - any use of an index will be billed one read per document matching a query.  The code you are showing right now will be billed one read for each document in the "products" collection.